# Choosing image from Assets it is not showing in Tab Bar Controller in SWIFT

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `ViewController` which is embed in `Tab Bar Controller`. I wanted to add custom icon to Tab Bar (in Main.storyboard), which is already exist in my Assets. When I do that, I don't see the icon but grey square. After when I run the app, I still have a grey square, not my own custom icon in .jpg. Describing picture bellow.

[Grey square in launched application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aO5VV.jpg)

[Grey square in Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwobB.jpg)

Can somebody help me, how to show my own icon?

Answer (score 1):

Check the alpha channel of your images. They should have some transparency. If not, `UITabBarItem` will show them as a square you've provided on the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a .png file possibly with some transparency in the image and make sure you have your image.png, image@2x.png and image@3x.png sizes in your Assets for retina etc.

If this doesn't work try just loading the image into a uiimageview to see if it loads okay. if it doesn't then it might be an issue with the image itself so you could try re saving it again.